# X-Editable - How to do "Custom input, several fields"

Tags: x-editable

I am playing around with x-editable and I am wondering how they do the last example in their demo page.

http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html?c=inline  (Custom input, several fields)

I can't find any thing that actually shows you the code for each part. I only can dig through it with firebug but that is more time consuming and I rather just see the parts I need.

Any have the pieces of code that does it?

Answer (score 12):

Yes, @marcb is right!

So here: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable

Or to be exact: https://github.com/vitalets/x-editable/blob/master/src/inputs-ext/address/address.js

Comment: For the lazy: `<a href="#" id="address" data-type="address" data-pk="1">value here</a>
    $('#address').editable({
        url: '/post',
        title: 'Enter city, street and building #',
        value: {
            city: "Moscow", 
            street: "Lenina", 
            building: "15"
        }
    });`

Comment: This is disappointing.  The support isn't there for an arbitrary set of custom fields as the label in the example suggests.  Actually it's support for a 3 field object corresponding to the `data-type="address"` field type, similar to how the `"combodate"` field type results in multiple inputs.  Yes, you could write your own extension similar to what's in address.js to handle a different or an arbitrary set of fields in the `value:` object, but that's not really an out of the box solution. :(

Answer (score 10):

The code for this can be found in the X-editable Bootstrap 3 download, under "inputs-ext", and then the "address" folder.

Comment: I don't 100% get it, do I have to make my own "address.js" class with all those methods?

Comment: essentially, yes. I personally haven't created a new class as I haven't needed to (yet), however it seems pretty well documented.